# Objective C framework with library dependency but no embedding

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm writing a framework Stuff.framework (for private use) that depends on a third party static library libthirdparty.a, but I don't want to embed the library in the framework. The framework will be used by SomeApp.app (among other things).

To keep things brief, let's just assume we agree that embedding is bad.

If I were writing a library libstuff.a rather than a framework, I'd simply not link libstuff.a with libthirdparty.a. SomeApp.app would link to both libstuff.a and libthirdparty.a – no problem.

This approach doesn't work for a framework. If Stuff.framework doesn't link libthirdparty.a, the linker gives "Undefined symbols" errors. If Stuff.framework does link libthirdparty.a, the contents of the library is embedded in the framework, which is what I want to avoid.

So, does anyone know how to achieve the aim stated in the first paragraph? I guess this is a difference between static and dynamic libraries, but perhaps there are linking options that can solve it.

Comment: You're trying to ask for dynamic bindings to a static library.  That really isn't going to happen.  What's wrong with the library being statically linked into the framework?  Also, linking and "embedding" are different concepts.  I'm not sure what you mean by embedding.

Comment: If the answer is "that's impossible", then fine - I'll stop wasting my time. My understanding is that the static library's code is copied into the framework. Say you have two frameworks that use the same library, and are both used by the app - now you have duplicate symbols in the app. Worse, what if the frameworks used different versions of the library? And/or the app itself also uses the library? Quite possible, eg. if they all use a given logging library.

Comment: This is OS X, right?  If you ship an intermediate dylib, your application will resolve symbols dynamically in that which will call the integrated static code in the dylib rather than having to deal with all of this shared static library nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic linking to the rescue!

A framework that statically links a piece of code from a static library will call into that static library's code whenever possible and not pollute your symbol-space.  Even when multiple copies of the same static library are linked into multiple frameworks, or even when one framework links with a copy of a static library that your application itself also links to, there are still two copies of the symbols.  One of these copies is local to your application and is what will be called, the other is local to the framework and that is all it will call.  So, relax.  The linker handles all of the necessaries for you.

In general, you're right, embedding is bad, but that only holds true now for static libraries where your fears would be entirely justified.  In that case, the linker would have duplicate symbols to integrate into the binary from multiple copies of a library.  It may just pick the first one it sees and move on, or it may emit duplicate symbol warnings.  Either way, not good.

Comment: Using dynamic libraries would indeed avoid the problem; that's not what I asked though, because there's a reason I'm stuck with static libraries (Cocoapods, although I don't want to make this a Cocoapods discussion). (Not sure what you're getting at in your second paragraph by the way - could it be that you said "static" when you meant "dynamic" in a few places?)

Comment: Stuff.framework is a dynamic library.  That's the point of this whole thing.